# Building glibc from source not compiling ldconfig

Tags: linux, build, compilation, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I've downloaded, built and installed glibc many times before and all was ok, this time `ldconfig` binary is not created and hence I am unable to update the /etc/ld.so.cache file correctly leading to a problem finding shared objetcts. The version of glibc with this behaviour is **glibc-2.20**, I am using a custom linux distribution built initially with the help of the **Linux From Scractch Book**, custom linux also and x86_64 architecture.

I've tried changing the `configure` options and also tried to compile without any option at all.

Comment: By the way, my english is not perfect obviously so if you have trouble understanding please ask for clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, there is a variable in the configure script `use_ldconfig` it was set to `no`, setting it to `yes` did solve the problem.